# compare two strings in java using command line arguments

Tags: java

Im a java noob. Basically I am trying to create a program that compares two command line arguments while ignoring case and prints out the lesser of the two strings. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class CompareStrings
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      String s1 = new String(args[0]);
      String s2 = new String(args[1]);

      if ( s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) > 0 )
         System.out.println(s2);
      else if ( s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2) < 0 )
         System.out.println(s1);
      else   
         System.out.println("Both strings are equal.");
   }
}
```

I keep getting the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class CompareString
```

when I try to run it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set your [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))?

Comment: Is that your *complete* file? How are you compiling it? How are you running it?

Comment: i want just to be clear about it: the problem is not with your code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> "Error: Could not find or load main class CompareString"

Your error message says you couldn't load class "CompareString", but your code says your class name is CompareString**s**.

Comment: +1 for being quicker :)

Comment: Dude, if you get two more upvotes, you'll get a badge soon :) that too your first answer on SO :) best luck

Comment: This answer needs to be accepted now.

Comment: Thanks alot, solved my issue. Accepted your answer :]

Answer (score 5):

Your class name is wrong.

Your error says

> Error: Could not find or load main class CompareString

but the name of class is `CompareStrings` not `CompareString`

launch using `java CompareStrings`

Read this good tutorial on [compiling and launching java programs](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are trying to use wrong class, should be `CompareStrings` and not `CompareString`.

Second, I would recommend using a nice utility lib for handling command line called [Cliche](https://code.google.com/p/cliche/) from Google Code site

And third, it would be good to check if the given string is null before you call `compareToIgnoreCase` on it

Answer (score 1):

as per your error i can gues that you are running CompareString but your class is CompareStrings
So either run java CompareStrings or rename your class to CompareString

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only code you have, save that file as `CompareStrings.java` not CompareString, and in command prompt `javac CompareStrings.java`. (to do this you need to configure java). then use `java CompareStrings abc cbs` to run this. and this will give you out put as `abc`